# Iterables behaving badly

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a bizarro issue which I just ran into ... when passed an array of objects, the `for..of` iterator has no problem iterating over the objects and giving me the "name" property of each. However, `array.forEach` completely fails to iterate.

The main function is found in `Database.ts`:

```
import { ITableDefinition } from "./Table";

export function Database(...tables: ITableDefinition<any>[]) {
  const names: string[] = [];
  for (const table of tables) {
    names.push(table.name);
  }

  return {
    tables,
    tableNames: tables.forEach((table) => table.name),
    tableNamesWithForOf: names,
  };
}
```

As you can see the function reflexively passes the array of *tables* it receives but also passes the *name* property of each table and it does it **twice**. Once using `forEach` and once using `for..of`.

When running the following Jest tests, 2 of the 3 pass but the forEach test fails:

```
describe("Trouble with iterables => ", () => {
  // db.tables is received as an array
  it("tables property is an array", () => {
    const db = Database(Table(Song), Table(Playlist));
    expect(Array.isArray(db.tables)).toBe(true);
    expect(typeof db.tables[0]).toBe("object");
  });

  // for..of iterates over the array correctly and extracts the "name" prop
  it("for ... of returns the names of the tables correctly", () => {
    const db = Database(Table(Song), Table(Playlist));

    expect(db.tableNamesWithForOf).toHaveLength(2);
    expect(db.tableNamesWithForOf).toContain("Song");
    expect(db.tableNamesWithForOf).toContain("Playlist");
  });

  // shockingly, forEach doesn't iterate at all and returns `undefined`!
  it("forEach returns the names of the tables correctly", () => {
    const db = Database(Table(Song), Table(Playlist));

    expect(db.tableNames).toHaveLength(2);
    expect(db.tableNames).toContain("Song");
    expect(db.tableNames).toContain("Playlist");
  });
});
```

My mind is blown but I'd love to hear from you if you can make some sense of it.

- [Git Repo](https://github.com/ksnyde/iterables-bahaving-badly) - all code and tests
- [GitPod Container](https://gitpod.io/#snapshot/7ca4058a-8a39-4c2b-9cfe-ee4dc7e103d6) ... new to GitPod, hopefully the link works (super convenient)

> Note: I tagged as both `javascript` and `typescript` but i doubt this has to with transpiling so if folks think I should take off the TS tag let me know and I'll do so.

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't return anything, it just processes the elements in the array.  Do you want `map()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forEach in `tables.forEach((table) => table.name)` doesn't return anything *i.e. returns undefined*, you can use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead